# Extract wikipedia articles belonging to a category from offline dumps

Tags: nlp, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikimedia-dumps

I have wikipedia article dumps in different languages. I want to filter them with articles which belong to a category(specifically [Category:WikiProject_Biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:WikiProject_Biography))

I could get a lot of similar questions for example:

1. [Wikipedia API to get articles belonging to a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242745/wikipedia-api-to-get-articles-belonging-to-a-category)
2. [How do I get all articles about people from Wikipedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017166/how-do-i-get-all-articles-about-people-from-wikipedia)

However, I would like to do it all offline. That is using dumps, and also for different languages.

Other things which I explored are category table and category link table.
[MediaWiki_1.28.0_database_schema](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/MediaWiki_1.28.0_database_schema.svg)

Comment: Yeah, the categorylinks table is what you need. So what is the problem?

Comment: Ok, so could you please describe how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the `page` and `categorylinks` tables from the dump, then run

```
SELECT
    page_namespace,
    page_title
FROM
    page
    JOIN categorylinks ON page_id = cl_from
WHERE
    cl_to = 'WikiProject_Biography'
;
```

to get the list of pages.