# creating a corpus of Wikipedia articles of specific field

Tags: data-mining, wikipedia

I want to create a corpus of biology-related articles from Wikipedia, so I could analyze it later using NLP approaches. I have downloaded a Wikipedia dump, and saved it in JSON format.

I am struggling with the task of extracting the biology-related articles. While I was able to find all the articles that are listed under the category "Biology" using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178266/extract-wikipedia-articles-belonging-to-a-category-from-offline-dumps), It turned out that only about 20 articles are listed directly under this category. I believe that I would be more lucky if I try to extract all the articles that belong to the biology **portal**, but I don't know how to do such a thing. Is there any method to extract articles that belong to a certain portal?

Answer (score 1):

Categories are nested. For example, "Animals" ID probably a subcategory of "Biology".

You need to find all (transitive) subcategories first, then collect the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia's categories are organized as a DAG, so you can traverse the tree considering the Biology category node as root and collect the associated Wiki articles. I did a similar thing before (with different intent) and sharing the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/wasiahmad/mining_wikipedia/tree/master/WikiNomy), it may help you.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your project. Does the final file at the end of this page: https://github.com/wasiahmad/mining_wikipedia/tree/master/WikiNomy contains all the categories in Wikipedia? I can't find the structure and how subcategories are determined.